# How to download files from a server with FTP(E)S?

Tags: java, apache, ftp, explicit, ftps

I've been looking all over for the answer but the closest thing I've found is just blame the server.

This is my code, for my application I'm using the Zehon library:

```
import com.zehon.BatchTransferProgressDefault;
import com.zehon.FileTransferStatus;
import com.zehon.exception.FileTransferException;
import com.zehon.ftps.FTPsClient;

public class UploadFolderSample {
/**
 * Please refer to http://www.zehon.com/FTPs_samples.htm for its full source code
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String host = "****";
    int port = 990;
    String username = "******";
    String password = "*******";
    String sendingFolder = "*******/";
    String destFolder = "ftpes:******/";

    try {
        com.zehon.ftps.FTPsClient ftps = new FTPsClient(host, port, username, password, false);
        ftps.folderExists(destFolder);
        int status  = ftps.sendFolder(sendingFolder, destFolder, new BatchTransferProgressDefault());

        if(FileTransferStatus.SUCCESS == status){
            System.out.println(sendingFolder + " got ftps-ed successfully to  folder "+destFolder);
        }
        else if(FileTransferStatus.FAILURE == status){
            System.out.println("Fail to ftps  to  folder "+destFolder);
        }
    } catch (FileTransferException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

}

And this is my error:

```
Thank you for using Zehon software (www.zehon.com).  
Please go to http://www.zehon.com/feedback.php to provide us your feedback about the product.
Please go to http://www.zehon.com/feature_request.php to submit bugs or feature requests.
com.zehon.exception.FileTransferException: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication.
    at com.zehon.ftps.FTPsClient.folderExists(FTPsClient.java:1239)
    at test.UploadFolderSample.main(UploadFolderSample.java:34)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication.
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:313)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:290)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP._connectAction_(FTP.java:396)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._connectAction_(FTPClient.java:796)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._connectAction_(FTPSClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:172)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:192)
    at com.zehon.ftps.FTPsClient.getFTPSClient(FTPsClient.java:1444)
    at com.zehon.ftps.FTPsClient.folderExists(FTPsClient.java:1236)
    ... 1 more
```

I could really use some help, I've been stuck on the FTPS thing for over a week now.

edit(added dialog):
This is what happens when I use the wrong port, but at least it shows the dialog this way.

```
> Thank you for using Zehon software (www.zehon.com).   Please go to
> http://www.zehon.com/feedback.php to provide us your feedback about
> the product. Please go to http://www.zehon.com/feature_request.php to
> submit bugs or feature requests. 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.33
> beta 220 Welcome by ***** AUTH TLS 234 Using authentication type TLS
> USER ***** 331 Password required for ***** PASS ******* 230 Logged on
> SYST 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla PASV 227 Entering Passive Mode
> (******) LIST ftpes:*****/ 550 PROT P required 220-FileZilla Server
> version 0.9.33 beta 220 Welcome by **** AUTH TLS 234 Using
> authentication type TLS USER **** 331 Password required for **** PASS
> **** 230 Logged on Transfer start for file ****\test.txt MODE S 200 MODE set to S. TYPE I 200 Type set to I PASV 227 Entering Passive Mode
> (*****) STOR ftpes:*****/test.txt 550 PROT P required Transfer error
> *****/test.txt Transfer complete for file *****/test.txt Transfer start for file *****/test.txt MODE S
```

Comment: Do you have the same symptom with command line FTP clients? If yes, try and debug with `lftp`

Comment: @fge Do you mean clients like FileZilla? Because then the answer is no, it is working perfectly through other clients. And thanks for the "lftp" tip :).

Comment: Can you trace the dialog with your API the same way that FileZilla can do?

Comment: @fge I think I know what you mean. I can do it if I set it to port 21 or set it to implicit instead of explicit: (added to original post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist Explicit and Implicit FTPS (FTP-over-SSL). In first case connection is established (usually) to port 21, then a command is sent to negotiate SSL over established channel. Implicit SSL means connection over port (usually) 990, then SSL is negotiated and then regular commands (LOGIN etc. ) are sent over SSL-secured channel.

If you mix two modes (connect to port 990 in non-secured mode or try to connect to port 21 and start SSL handshake immediately), nothing will work.

So first thing to do is find out what mode you need to use. Then you set correct port and check that your library supports needed mode.

Comment: If I set it to implicit and port 21 I get this message "com.zehon.exception.FileTransferException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?" 
My boss said he was sure it was explicit over port 990, the URL the server gives is ftpes as well.

Comment: @ArnoudAarnoudse your updated error message makes sense - explicit FTPS works fine, and the problem happens when trying to open data connection. This can be caused by the server, the component or both - it's hard to say without debugging and some experiments. If you use PROT C (clear/non-ssl mode for data channel) - try it.

Comment: So in the end it might actually be server related? The server is outsourced and I'm just an intern so I don't have full controll over the server, even though they did give me the admin account. I'll look into the PROT C. My boss told me that if I couldn't finish it before tomorrow he would outsource it, but this will still be a usefull learning experience if I ever were to work with (S)FTP(S) again. So thanks for the help :)

Comment: @ArnoudAarnoudse While it can be a server problem (though unlikely), I'd blaim the client - either the component has problems or it needs special setup. You can try with other FTPS implementations to exclude some of possibilities. On a side note don't confuse SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) with FTPS - these are completely different protocols.

Comment: We filed a ticket.
Looks like my boss was wrong for a couple of years. The server doesn't allow FTPS acces(even though there is a certificate), only regular FTP through port 21 ..........................
Still thanks for the help! And yes I did keep SFTP and FTPS apart :) Guess you can't do anything about human mistakes... :(